# jquery css backgroud color not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the background of selected href , which is not 
       working for me. i can see selected href in console log. Can someone 
       help me understand if i am missing anything in my code ?

```
 Below is my code:
 -----------------
 <style>
    .current {
        background-color: tomato;
   }
 </style>

  function getwlan() {
       $.ajax({
       url: '/getwlan',
       data: $('form').serialize(),
       type: 'POST',
       success: function(response){
         var wlan = JSON.parse(response);
         var options = "";
         var row = $('<tr>');
         var zone="<b>System Zones</b>";
         for (var i = 0; i < wlan.length; i++) {
           if (wlan[i].wlan_zone){
            z1=new Array (wlan[i].wlan_zone)
            zone += "<a href="+'"' +z1 +'"'+"><h5>"+ z1 + "</h5></a>";
             }
            } 
           $("#divzone").html(zone); 
           $('#divzone a').on('click', function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               var v=($(this).attr('href'));
               var s1= sessionStorage.setItem('zones', v);
               var s2=sessionStorage.getItem("zones");
               console.log(v)
               $(this).addClass('current');
               var section_id = $(this).attr('href');
               var section_color = $(section_id).css('background-color');
               $(this).css('background-color', section_color);
```

'

Comment: can you console log section_color

Comment: what is section id? how it get it from `href` attribute of anchor tag

Comment: I don't understand the JS logic. section_id is the 'href' of the link. Now you're trying to get the background color of an 'href' and set that to the link that the href came from. Or am I missing something.

Comment: [here is your answer with working demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831696/jquery-css-backgroud-color-not-working/45832132#45832132)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example this is relavent to your question :

```js
$('#divzone a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#divzone a').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  });
```

```css
.current {
        background-color: tomato;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='divzone'>
  <a class='link'>href</a>
  <a class='link'>href</a>
  <a class='link'>href</a>
  <a class='link'>href</a>
  <a class='link'>href</a>
  <a class='link'>href</a>
  <a class='link'>href</a>
</div>
```

Comment: if worked then mark this answer so others can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Change the link background based on the clicked link with color of section id that contain in href attribute of clicked link.

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  $('a').css('background-color','');
  var sectionId = $(this).attr('href');
  var backgroundColor = $(sectionId).css('background-color');
  $(this).css('background-color', backgroundColor);
})
```

```css
  

  a{
      padding: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    div{
      
      height: 100px;
    }

    #sectionID1 {
      background-color: #337ab7;
    }

    #sectionID2 {
      background-color: #ffcc00;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#sectionID1">Section 1</a>
<a href="#sectionID2">section 2</a>

<div id="sectionID1">
  Section 1
</div>

<div id="sectionID2">
  Section 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add !important on `.current background-color` to override any other [same / more important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) declarations.

```
.current {
    background-color: tomato !important;
}
```

Or this

```
#divzone a.current {
    background-color: tomato !important;
}
```

Comment: rephrasing my question, actually i am trying to change the background of second z1 in the code, essentially it is a text which need to change background color on click and back to origional color if off clicked.         
  >>>> zone += "<a href="+'"' +z1 +'"'+"><h5>"+ z1 + "</h5></a>";